skaffold + helm + Google Cloud Deploy: dependency update from private helm repo
It looks like Skaffold doesn't pull the remote dependencies from a private helm repo and it's not clear to me how to set the credentials to get authenticated with this private helm repo.
This is my chart. It is a local chart, in the sense that I deploy it from a cloned git repo. It declares some remote dependencies from a remote private helm repo.
### Chart.yaml ###

apiVersion: v2
name: foo-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "0.0.1"

dependencies:
  - name: hello-world
    version: 3.2.0
    repository: "https://example.com/repository/helm"
  ...

This is my skaffold.yaml
### skaffold.yaml ###

apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta7
kind: Config
profiles:
  - name: preprod
    deploy:
      helm:
        releases:
          - name: foo
            createNamespace: true
            namespace: default
            chartPath: ./helm
            repo: https://example.com/repository/helm
            skipBuildDependencies: true
            valuesFiles:
              - envs/preprod/values.yaml
            setValueTemplates:
              image.tag: "0.0.1"
  - name: prod
    deploy:
      helm:
        releases:
          - name: foo
            createNamespace: true
            namespace: default
            chartPath: ./helm
            repo: https://example.com/repository/helm
            valuesFiles:
              - envs/prod/values.yaml
            setValueTemplates:
              image.tag: "0.0.1"

I run this skaffold through Google Deploy. This is the cloudbuild.yaml
### cloudbuild.yaml ###
...
- name: 'google/cloud-sdk:latest'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        gcloud config set deploy/region ${_REGION}
        gcloud deploy apply --file deploy/pipeline.yaml
        gcloud deploy apply --file deploy/preprod.yaml
        gcloud deploy apply --file deploy/prod.yaml
        gcloud deploy releases create rel-${SHORT_SHA} \
                --delivery-pipeline foo-pipeline-deploy \
                --description "$(git log -1  --pretty='%s')" \
                --annotations "commit_ui=https://source.cloud.google.com/$PROJECT_ID/foo-helm/+/$COMMIT_SHA"

The error returned by Google Deploy is
An error occurred while checking for chart dependencies. You may need to run "helm dependency build" to fetch missing dependencies: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/
Any suggestion?
EDIT: I've also tried to use skipBuildDependencies: false but I get the error building helm dependencies: exit status 1
